# Patching windows with AWS system patch manager using script

Tags: windows, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Is it possible to run the aws patch manager for windows using lambda?

We have 2 server behind ELB. Now we want to perform following action.
1. Remove 1st server from ELB.
2. Patch this windows server.
3. Add the server back to ELB.
4. Perform the same things with other server.

I'm not sure how to perform step 2.
I can see that patch can be scheduled from the AWS console -> Patch manager but not able to find out if I can trigger patch baseline to any targeted instance using lambda.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: I was able to resolve it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying to perform almost the exact same thing, however I'm having trouble with step 1 and 3. My idea is to use Maintenance Window tasks to coordinate the steps. The maintenance window would call the step 1 lambda function, then instead of lambda, use run-command for step 2, then lambda for step 3. Can you share your lambda function for removing/adding instances to the ELB? Thanks!

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. You can [search for similar questions](//stackoverflow.com/search), or refer to the related and linked questions on the right-hand side of the page to find an answer. If you have a related but different question, [ask a new question](//stackoverflow.com/questions/ask), and include a link to this one to help provide context. See: [Ask questions, get answers, no distractions](//stackoverflow.com/tour)